# Flutter Checkbox/CheckBoxListTile vertical Alignment options

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This is simplified example of what Im working on

```
return SizedBox(
  width: 300,
  height: 200,
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const Text('text line'),
        Row(
          children: [
            Checkbox(
                value: false,
                onChanged: (bool? value) {}),
            const Expanded(
                child: Text(
                    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,'
                    'sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna'
                    'aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation'
                    'ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Since Im trying to vertical Align the checkbox(leading) in the row with the 3 lines of text(trailing).

Is it possible to modify the vertical alignment of the checkbox without having to go with a fully custom widget, like using a stack/positioned?

I have tried modifying with visual density, transform.translate with very little vertical control.
I tried to also both CheckBox and CheckBoxListTile using controlAffinity.leading, contentpadding.zero.

[image]

Comment: can you include   current(minimal) snippet that will reproduce the same issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Updated post to reproduce as well as a picture showing the vertical space I am trying to control.

Answer (score 1):

Use `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,` on Row.

```dart
SizedBox(
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const Text('text line'),
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Checkbox(value: false, onChanged: (bool? value) {}),
              const Expanded(
                child: Text(
                    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,'
                    'sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna'
                    'aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation'
                    'ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a working solution, it's horizontal min value is -4 visual density is used for compactness.
visualDensity:VisualDensity(horizontal: -4.0, vertical: -4.0),

Shrinks the tap target size to the minimum provided by the Material specification.
materialTapTargetSize:MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
      child: Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
          materialTapTargetSize:
              MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
          visualDensity:
              VisualDensity(horizontal: -4.0, vertical: -4.0),
        ),
        child: Checkbox(
          value: _isChecked,
          onChanged: (newValue) {
            FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
            setState(() {
              _isChecked = newValue!;
              print(newValue);
            });
          },
          side: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.grey.shade400,
              style: BorderStyle.solid,
              width: 2),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          text: 'I agree to the ',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
          children: <TextSpan>[
            TextSpan(
              text: 'Terms of Service',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors
                    .blue, // Set your desired color for the Terms o
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: ' and ',
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: 'Privacy Policy',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors
                    .blue, // Set your desired color for the Privacy
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use [CheckboxListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CheckboxListTile-class.html)

```
 CheckboxListTile(
                    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                    title: Text('In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available.'),
                    value: true, onChanged: (value) {}),
```

Comment: ListTileControlAffinity controls where the checkbox will be horizontally positioned